# Executing shell script through java program

Tags: java, shell

I am trying to execute shell script through java program but the script is not executing completely.

Script:

shell.sh
./MetaMatch.sh songsMetaData.json > songsResult.json

Though it is printing songsResult.json file but empty.

Comment: what java code have you tried so far?

Comment: Where is the java code?

Comment: You probably have a different environment than what the one you expect (I'd guess the current directory is wrong and ./MetaMatch.sh does not correspond to any file).

Answer (score 0):

You can use java ProcessBuilder  to execute shell script in local machine. You can find lot of example in google one of them is http://esudharaka.blogspot.in/2012/06/executing-shell-script-from-java-class.html . If shell script is in remote host than you have to use libraries like [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)